# Zkoss-8.5.1 Problem creating data binding programmatically

Tags: java, data-binding, binding, zk

I'm creating a zk component for mount easy grid from view database. One of its powerful features is the automatic generation of filters by column. These filters appear automatically on the top column inside the auxheader tag and all are generated programmatically in java with the column info. Example of database view TIMESTAMP column (sorry not css right now):

https://prnt.sc/ZK9nMws2l68p

My problem now is that I don't know how to bind these datebox generated programmatically in java with the view for recovering the filter values.

I was searching inside the zkoss wiki and only found this:

[create data binding programmatically](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/User:Hawk/Create_Data_Binding_Programmatically),

where you can find how bind zk components of the zul, or how bind components generated programatically if the parent has an item render option.

**But i need generate N datebox, numberbox, textbox depending on the number and type of the columns and recover the values of it.**

Anyone knows how do it?

The component has a loot of code and scrap, but more or less the idea is:

https://pastebin.com/Q5VX472L

```
    cols.setParent(gridDatatable);
    // create filters inside AuxHeads
    Auxhead auxhead1 = new Auxhead();
    // create a line with the same number of AuxHeaders as Columns we have
    for (int indexColumn = 0; indexColumn < columnsList
        .size(); indexColumn++) {
      if (columnsList.get(indexColumn).getVisible()) {
        // i have definned the diferent Auxheader with a patron factory
        Auxheader auxheader = gridDatatableFilterFactory.generateFilter(
            columnsList.get(indexColumn).getTerms().getType(),
            columnsList.get(indexColumn).getTerms().getKey());
        auxheader.setParent(auxhead1);
      }
    }
    // set the Auxhead line between col names and rows
    auxhead1.setParent(gridDatatable);
    // we add the rowrender for print the rows
    gridDatatable.setRowRenderer(
        new DatatableRowRender(columnsList, gridDatatableCellFactory));
    search();
```

Thank you in advance, regards.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: posted a long-form answer here: https://forum.zkoss.org/question/114206/problem-creating-data-binding-programmatically/